# KMP algorithm, can't understand

Tags: java, algorithm

I have difficulty in understanding KMP algorithm. I understand what prefix-suffix is and I wrote code to calculate prefix-suffix table :

```
 private int[] calculatePrefSuffArray(String pattern) {
    char patternArray[] = pattern.toCharArray();
    int tab[] = new int[pattern.length()];
    tab[0] = 0;
    int t = tab[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < pattern.length(); i++) { // t = tab[i-1]
        while(t >0 && patternArray[i] != patternArray[t] ) {
            t = tab[t-1];
        }
        if(patternArray[i] == patternArray[t]) t++;
        tab[i] = t;
    }
    return tab;
}
```

but I can't understand how to use it in KMP. Could someone explain it for me ?

Answer (score 3):

**Naive Algorithm**

In the normal pattern matching algorithm, if you have a pattern of length
**m** and text of length **n**, m characters of the pattern will be matched
against n characters of the text usually, though you could circumvent this behaviour a bit by using an exit function to avoid some of the matches if a mismatch has already occurred.

So the asymptotic complexity of the algorithm is O(mn).

But the problem with the naive algorithm is that it doesn't try to understand anything about the pattern. For example, if you are working in a company for 5 years, you could use the 5 years of experience to your advantage someway. Likewise, we could analyze the substring and infer some useful information about this. This is exactly what you are doing when calculating the **prefix function.**

**KMP Algorithm**

[image: An example KMP search]

Since we have found a substring of the pattern that matches the text, is it not better to **slide the pattern right** 6(position where the substring match is found) - 1(prefix function of position 6) times and restart comparison straight away instead of again going the naive way? In fact prefix function values are used to determine **how many times the pattern has to be slided right**. This might be a bit difficult to understand initially but take a piece of paper and compare a small text against a small pattern writing down the intermediate values of all the variables and then you will appreciate how beautiful this algorithm is.

The asymptotic complexity of this algorithm is O(m+n), since we are sliding past
the pattern every-time a mismatch occurs.

**A c++ implementation of the algorithm is given below :**
**Program 1**: Creating a pattern of size 10000000 and storing it in a file, inputtext.txt(you could change the size. Perhaps!)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

  main()
  {
    ofstream myfile("inputtext.txt");
    char *intxt="abcd"; // I wish the sample text to contain only these alphabets
    long int i=0;
    char* txt = new char[10000000];
    while(i<10000000)
       {
       txt[i]=intxt[(rand()%4)]; 
       i++;
       }
   myfile<<txt;
   myfile.close();
  }
```

**Program2** : Pattern search using the KMP algorithm.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

 void prefix_fn(int* p, char* s)
 {
 s--;
 p--;
 int i,k=0;
   p[1]=0;
   for(i=2;i<=7;i++)
   {
     while ((k>0)&&(s[k+1]!=s[i]))
         k=p[k];
     if (s[k+1]==s[i])     
         k++;
     p[i]=k;
   }
 }
main()
{
int i,k;
int *p= new int[7];
char* txt=new char[10000000];
ifstream myfile("inputtext.txt");
myfile.seekg(0,ios::beg);

myfile.read(txt,10000000);
myfile.close();
char *s="abdcbab";
cout<<"Prefix Table"<<endl;
prefix_fn(p,s);
p--; // This helps to start indexing from 1, just for me to avoid confusion
s--; // Similar objective as stated above.
   for(int i=1;i<=7;i++)
      cout<<p[i]<<endl;
txt--;
k=0;
  for(i=1;i<=10000000;i++)
    {
       while(k>0 && s[k+1]!=txt[i])
           {
            k=p[k]; 
           }
       if(s[k+1]==txt[i])
           {
            k=k+1;
           }
        if(k==7)
           {
            cout<<"Match found at position : "<<i-6<<endl;
            k=p[k]; 
           }
    }
p++;
delete[] p; 
txt++;
delete[] txt; //deleting the memory allocated.
}
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your `calculatePrefSuffArray("ABC ABCDAB ABCDABCDABDE")` will return this

```
[0  0  0  0  1  2  3  0  1  2  0  1  2  3  0  1  2  3  0  1  2  0  0]
```

instead of this

```
[-1  0  0  0  1  2  3  0  1  2  0  1  2  3  0  1  2  3  0  1  2  0  0 ]
```

Correct your code by replacing following

```
tab[0] = 0;
int t = tab[0];
```

with this

```
tab[0] = -1;
tab[1] = 0;
int t = tab[1];
```

pass created `int[] table` returned from your `calculatePrefSuffArray(String pattern)` function.
It will return `true` if `word` is found in `string` text.

```
private boolean search(String string, String word, int[] table) {
    int m = 0, i = 0;
    while ((m + i) < string.length()) {
        if (word.charAt(i) == string.charAt(m + i)) {
            if (i == word.length() - 1) {
                return true;
            }
            i++;
        } else {
            if (table[i] > -1) {
                m = m + i - table[i];
                i = table[i];
            } else {
                i = 0;
                m++;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Let me know if you have any problem in understanding the code.

Comment: Why it is not correct ? Unfortunately,I can't understand your method search. Could you explain in plain english the idea of this method ? I want to print all occurences of pattern in text

Comment: Have a look at the algorithm [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm). It is just an implementation of the algorithm present here. I edited my post to let you correct your program.

Comment: I am sorry! your algorithm is correct according to the theory. But it is not matching the algorithm that I am showing you. Tell me if you want to work on your algorithm instead of this, which is taken from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm). @Yewm

Comment: but why we need this - 1 ? I think that tab[i] means the length of longest prefix-suffix in prefix i, so how it might be -1 ?

Comment: According to algorithm this -1 will be used to know the start of array and it could be used in further exceptional cases and is being used inside last else part. Don't worry, your code is correct. you are needed to check start of array yourself to work it with your code. But I prefer this algorithm. Tell me if you want me to post answer your way.

Comment: If you want, It'll be nice. Thank you Could you also write idea of searching pattern if we have this prefix-suffix table calculated ?

Comment: (If you want, It'll be nice) Did you mean by this I may post answer according to your algo? And Please refer to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm). It is nicely explained there. But in short : with table algo is letting you not to search only necessary characters and hence reducing time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

afzalex has explained it well.

But if you are not clear even now then I found this piece of article very simple to 
understand.
May be it could be helpful : http://www.algorithmwebschool.com/index.php/kmp-algorithm/

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution(object):
    def strStr(self, haystack, needle):
        """
        :type haystack: str
        :type needle: str
        :rtype: int
        """

        if not needle:
            return 0

        q = 0
        preList = self.calPre(needle)
        # print preList
        for i in xrange(len(haystack)):
            # print needle[q], haystack[i], i
            while q>0 and needle[q] != haystack[i]:  # 加入循环，让累加子串充分比较，直到q变成0，防止haystack中有元素未参与可能相等的比较
                q = preList[q]
            if needle[q] == haystack[i]:    
                q += 1
            if q == len(needle): 
                return i - len(needle) + 1    # 比较完毕
        return -1 

    def calPre(self, s):
        preList = [0, 0]
        i = 1
        j = 0
        while i < len(s):
            if s[i] == s[j]:     # 进行子串累加匹配
                preList.append(j+1)
                i += 1
                j += 1
            elif s[i] == s[0]:  # 重新开始子串匹配
                j = 0
            else:                  # 无法匹配 
                preList.append(0)
                i += 1
                j = 0
        return preList
```

This is the KMP algorithm I wrote by Python.
I hope that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

To Understand KMP algorithm, you need to understand

1. How to construct "Partial Match Table" by using the pattern string.
   [This Link](http://jakeboxer.com/blog/2009/12/13/the-knuth-morris-pratt-algorithm-in-my-own-words/) explains the "Partial Match Table" Construction technique with very simple words.
2. How to use the above "Partial Match Table" to find out the next search start position for both "search text" and "pattern string". [This Link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/searching-for-patterns-set-2-kmp-algorithm/) has a nice video which explains that in detail.

Answer (score 0):

KMP and prefix function is pretty much the same thing.
In KMP case you combine pattern with text first, and then generate prefix array from the combo string. When prefix function = length of pattern, it means pattern is inside the  text.

- pattern: p = ABC, len(p) = 3
- Text: T = XYABCYZ
- combo = ABC_XYABCYZ (p and T separated by a character that is not in
  either p or T, this will guarantee prefix function will not exceed
  length of p)
- prefix function of ABC_XYABC = 3, so Text contain pattern.